# How can I check if a cell in Excel spreadsheet contains number

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of addresses and I have to find those which don't contain street numbers. Unfortunately, addresses have been input by various users and they do not follow the same pattern so the street type, street name, suburb are in different order and I can't use functions like LEFT, RIGHT or MID to check if particular character is a number. The column looks like this:

```
    10 Willsons Drive, Manhattan
    Epping, 23 Wet Rd
    Longsdale St, Kingsbury
    11 Link Crt, Pakenham
```

Is there an Excel or VBA function that can tell me if cell / string contains numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution?  Or a formula?

Comment: Write VBA macro `Function` to split cell values and use `IsNumeric()` to check for numbers. If all cell values does not have one then return a boolean value.

Comment: `If s Like "*#*" Then`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this into a Module, then in your worksheet, may be a column next to it, put formula `=HaveNumbers(A2)` and check if you want it like that (True/False). You can change it to Return a String instead. This Returns TRUE / FALSE.

```
Function HaveNumbers(oRng As Range) As Boolean
     Dim bHaveNumbers As Boolean, i As Long        
     bHaveNumbers = False
     For i = 1 To Len(oRng.Text)
         If IsNumeric(Mid(oRng.Text, i, 1)) Then
             bHaveNumbers = True
             Exit For
         End If
     Next
     HaveNumbers = bHaveNumbers
End Function
```

Comment: Surely Tim Williams' comment on the original question (i.e. `If s Like "*#*" Then bHaveNumbers = True` is more elegant?  Or does the `Like` operator have such an odious time implication that looping through the string is actually more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single VBA function that will do what you want, but the following function should do the trick:

```
Public Function ContainsNumbers(Inp As String) As Boolean
    Dim Strings() As String, Str As Variant
    Strings = Split(Inp, " ")
    For Each Str In Strings
        If IsNumeric(Str) Then
            ContainsNumbers = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then put something like `=ContainsNumbers(A1)` in a nearby cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Monty. In my case, though, numbers were not always separated from words so I had to iterate over each character. I used following:

```
Function ContainsNumber(text As String)
 'checks if given cell contains number

For i = 1 To Len(text)
    If IsNumeric(Mid$(text, i, 1)) Then
        ContainsNumber = True
    Exit Function
End If
Next
ContainsNumber = False

End Function
```